# drawLine() using double variables instead of integers

Tags: java, java-2d

I would like to ask whether it is possible to draw a line using double variables instead of integers. If yes how?

Comment: Why would you need a double? You wouldn't draw a line that is 22.3px long for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Line2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.Double.html). Use [Graphics2D.draw()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) to draw it.

See [Drawing Geometric Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
             Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
             Graphics2D g2 = aPaintContext.getGraphics();
             for (double x = bx; x < rightBorder; x += 5) {
                line.setLine(x, by, x, bottomBorder);
                g2.draw(line);
```